# How to connect and use GSM Modem

Tags: gsm

I want to connect SMS message with GSM Modem (WAVECOM WMO2 Modem Series GSM 900/1800/1900). But I don't how to connect and use it. Could anybody guide to connect with this modem.
I want to send SMS message with this also!

Thanks,
Sopolin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll need a serial cable to start off with.  Then send it some AT Commands from something like HyperTerminal or PuTTY on windows, or minicom or kermit on Linux.

All the info you need is in this manual. http://www.omniinstruments.net/radiotel/WMO2-Manual.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the serial cable, you could try using [gnokii](http://www.gnokii.org).